# Lambda function's body enclosed with parentheses?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm using someone else's utility method, and it appears to be using lambda expression syntax that I'm having trouble reading. An argument is defined

```
Func<Action<int>, Action<Exception>, EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>> getCompleteHandler
```

with Func's prototype being

```
delegate TResult System.Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

In the example code, the method is called with:

```
getCompleteHandler: (Action<int> complete, Action<Exception> reject) =>
                      (
                        (object sender, CustomEventArgs args) =>
                        {
                            complete(args.IntVar);
                        }
                      )
```

At the second line of the call, a parenthesis directly follows the first lambda operator, enclosing the inner lambda. I haven't seen this syntax anywhere else, but there is an entire lambda expression where I would expect nothing more than a typecast and a method body. What does the inner lambda represent to getCompleteHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = 1; x = (1); x = ((1)); x = ..`.

The (grouping) parenthesis are effectively ignored. The coder may have chosen the syntax because it added clarity (to him/her) or otherwise conformed to some convention; this use of parenthesis does not change the parsing or semantics at all.

Personally, I would not have added the parenthesis.

---

Evaluating the outer lambda-as-Func return the inner lambda-as-Action, forming a closure over `complete`. The returned Action is evaluated later on.

Imagine:

```
// -> Func<Action<int>, Action<Exception>,      // arguments
//         Action<object, CustomEventArgs>>     // return value
var getCompleteHandler = /* that */

// create the completion handler by invoking the "get" function
// -> Action<object, CustomEventArgs>           // same as return value
var completionHandler = getCompletionHandler(
   (x) => Console.WriteLine(x),
   (ex) => Console.WriteLine("Exception!: " + ex));

// call the completion handler any number of times..
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(42)) {
  completionHandler(this, new CustomEventArgs { IntVar = i });
}
```